# Add type column to Sandcastle Property table

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xslt, documentation, sandcastle

So I'm generating a documentation website using Sandcastle Help File Builder.  Everything is generated great!  However, when looking at a page for a class, I'd like for the Properties table (which currently has the icon, name, and description columns, see below) to include a column for the type of property (int, bool, string, etc).

[image: Properties Table]

I was reading somewhere about the xsl files that are used for the templates, but honestly it was a little overwhelming trying to find exactly what I'm looking for.

So basically, I'd like to add a column to the above table that lists the type (string, int, etc).  Is that possible?  Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to _manually_ include the type in the description using a <see cref="Address"> tag in the summary comment. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx

Comment: Did you ever figure this out.  I came here to post this exact same question.

Comment: Not entirely.  The best I could come up with was based on @Darragh suggestion.  I'll post an answer with some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately after a lot of searching I still haven't been able to find a way to do it exactly as I wanted (as a separate column).  The best, as Darraugh pointed out, is to include it manually in the description.  There are two ways of doing this.  Using the [`<See>` tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) or using the [`<seealso>` tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhd7ehkk.aspx).

The `<see>` tag can be used as such:

```
/// <summary>
/// Assessment ID to be copied
/// <see cref="System.Int32">System.Int32</see>
/// </summary>
```

And produces the following:

[image: <see> tag sample]

The `<seealso>` tag can be used as such:

```
/// <summary>
/// Assessment ID to be copied
/// <seealso cref="System.Int32"/>
/// </summary>
```

And produces the following:

[image: <seealso> tag sample]

This is a little redundant since you have to go into the property in order to see it, which already displays the property type.

Hopefully this answer will become obsolete at some point when this is implemented into sandcastle itself.  But for right now this may help other as it has helped me.